# How do I use specific data points on a graph to determine an equation?

Tags: logarithms, regression, data-analysis

I need to find a function $f(x)$ such that the following data points would fit on it:
$$f(1) = 0 \\
f(2) = 0.5 \\
f(4) = 1.0 \\
f(8) = 1.5 \\
\cdots $$
and so on.  So the pattern is every time $x$ doubles $f(x)$ increases by $0.5$.

What is the equation for $f(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function where multiplying the argument by a fixed factor results in adding a fixed constant to the output is (more or less by definition) a logarithmic function, not a quadratic function. Specifically, it must be a function of the form $f(x) = c \log x + d$ for some real numbers $c$ and $d$, which you can determine by plugging in a couple of given values.

Comment: You are the man.  The answer is

f(x) = log(x)/2

Comment: @user1068636 : $\log_4 x$ is consistent with what you wrote.  It's $(\log x)/2$ provided "$\log$" means the base-$2$ logarithm.

Answer (score 2):

If you plot $f(x)$ ([W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%5B%281%2C+0%29%2C+%282%2C+0.5%29%2C+%284%2C+1%29%2C+%288%2C+1.5%29%2C+%2816%2C+2%29%2C+%2832%2C+2.5%29%2C+%2864%2C+3%29%2C+%28128%2C+3.5%29%2C+%28256%2C+4%29%5D)), the graph should give you a clue that this is a logarithmic function. Also, you can consider the fact that what you have is a [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation): $f(x) = f(x/2) + 0.5$, which you solve using a technique such as [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_2). Or for example using [W|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29+%3D+f%28x%2F2%29+%2B+0.5).